# How can I change the format of Grafana query-variable from int to date using Timescale query?

Tags: grafana, timescaledb

I'm trying to create a query-variable using a Timescale data source.
This is my query:
`select distinct datetime from test`
And what i get is:

```
Preview of values
All
1614556801000
1617235201000
1619827201000
1622505601000
1630454401000
```

The desired result would be a human readable date format.
The solution suggested here doesn't work as I use Timescale:
https://community.grafana.com/t/date-format-changing-to-epoch-time-format-when-assigned-as-a-variable/51812

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it applies to your use-case but for a similar problem, I ended up rewriting my SQL query like this:

```sql
SELECT to_char(datetime,'MM-DD') AS "time"
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You, this has led me to a solution:

`select  distinct to_char(datetime, 'yyyy-MM-DD') from test`

Comment: Welcome to SO! As you are a new member, you cannot make comments. Your reply is a comment rather than an answer. In fact it is the same that you already received. Please, just introduce an answer when it is new.